# C++ dynamic memory allocation with mxArray

Tags: c++, matlab, memory-management

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
MATFile *file = matOpen(this->filename.c_str(),"r");
mxArray *roadstruct = matGetVariable(file, "ROAD");
mxArray *field;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < this->roadFields.size(); i++) {
field = mxGetFieldByNumber(roadstruct,0,i);
if(field != NULL) {
this->road[this->roadFields.at(i).c_str()] = *mxGetPr(field);
}
}
```

Where `this->road` is a `std::map<std::string, double>` and `this->roadFields` is a `std::vector<std::string>` containing all the field names of the ROAD struct in the .mat file.

I get an access violation in the `mxGetPr` call and I guess it's due to the fact that the arrays returned have different lengths? I think I need to reallocate memory somehow, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: What on Earth is the purpose of having a member that is a *pointer* to a `std::vector`?

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to reserve all uppercase names for macros, in order to avoid inadvertent name collisions and text substitution.

Comment: One potential problem is the C style cast in `*(double*) mxGetPr(ptr)`. Either the cast is unnecessary, or it's wrong. That said, please do post a **minimal but complete** example that exhibits problem.

Comment: Thanks, the code looks cleaner now, but I still have the same problem. I stripped away all the code around the issue, so now it should be a lot clearer.

Comment: Your code still isn't complete. Please include the *declarations of all variables* used in the snippet. And I guess with `std::map(std::string, double)` you mean `std::map<std::string, double>`?

Comment: Ok, I added the declarations that I removed when Alf asked for the minimal amount of code. :D   Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

`mxGetFieldByNumber()` returns NULL for certain errors.  Since your segfault occurs on `mxGetPr()`, it suggests that you're passing it something illegal, and that something illegal could be NULL.

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetfieldbynumber.html) for this function says that common errors that result in a NULL return are:

- Specifying an array pointer pm that does not point to a structure mxArray. Call mxIsStruct to determine whether pm points to a structure mxArray.
- Specifying an index to an element outside the bounds of the mxArray. For example, given a structure mxArray that contains ten elements, you cannot specify an index greater than 9 in C (10 in Fortran).
- Specifying a nonexistent field number. Call mxGetFieldNumber to determine the field number that corresponds to a given field name.

Check the return value from `mxGetFieldByNumber()`, and if it really is NULL, go through the above list and check your input conditions.

Comment: I added a NULL check, and the problem persists, so the `field` variable should be fine. I still think it's a memory allocation issue of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Part of the problem was a stupid mistake where a couple of field names in the `std::vector<std::string>` didn't exactly match the field names in the ROAD struct. But I also had to use memcpy (seems obvious now).

The contents of the for loop now looks like this, and it works!

```
size_t arraySize = mxGetNumberOfElements(field)*sizeof(double);
this->road[this->roadFields.at(i).c_str()] = (double*) malloc(arraySize);
memcpy(this->road[this->roadFields.at(i).c_str()],mxGetPr(field),arraySize);
```

Thanks of all the help.